# Error: stream.push() after EOF

Tags: node.js, stream

Playing with node steams

This code reads from index.js and writes to indexCopy.js - kind of file copy.
Target file got created, but during execution exception is thrown:

```
node index.js
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: stream.push() after EOF
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:240:30)
    at MyStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at ReadStream.f.on (C:\Node\index.js:16:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at ReadStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at fs.read (fs.js:2042:12)
    at FSReqWrap.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:658:17)

C:\Node>
```

This is code:

```
var util = require('util');
var stream = require('stream');
var fs = require('fs');


var MyStream = function(){
    stream.Readable.call(this)
}

util.inherits(MyStream,stream.Readable);


MyStream.prototype._read = function(d){

    f = fs.createReadStream("index.js");
    f.on('data',(d)=>{this.push(d)});
    f.on('end',()=>{this.push(null)}); //when file finished need to close stream

}


var f = fs.createWriteStream("indexCopy.js")

var myStream = new MyStream()
myStream.pipe(f);
```

I tried to call this.push(null) in 'data' event, in that case even target file is not created and code fails with the exception.

I realize that copy file should be done easier with pipe() function - I am just experimenting/learning.
What is wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 3):

You don't want the `f = fs.createReadStream("index.js")` line inside the `_read` method -- `_read` gets called repeatedly so you're creating multiple read streams. Put that in your constructor instead.

```
function MyStream () {
    stream.Readable.call(this);
    this.source = fs.createReadStream("index.js");
    this.haveBound = false;
}
MyStream.prototype._read = function () {
    if (this.haveBound) return; // Don't bind to events repeatedly
    this.haveBound = true;
    this.source.on("data", d => this.push(d));
    this.source.on("end", () => this.push(null));
};
```

This is awkward though. Streams are meant to be `pipe`'ed.